# Spring MVC 3 I18N/MessageSource not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-3

I am trying to configure internazionalization in Spring MVC (using changing of locales via links), however, it doesn't seem to be working at all: default locale is always ru for some reason, though default is set to en, they are not changing using links, spring messages are displayed empty regardless of the chosen locale (messages_de, messages_en and messages_ru.properties DO exist at classpath (src/main/resources)). They contain e.g.

```
label.test=Russian
```

and i refer to them as

```
<spring:message code="label.test" />
```

in my JSPs. They are not being displayed like that.
I take it as even messageSource is not found, even though there are no errors or warnings. I'd really appreciate any help as I'm trying to figure it out for really long time. Apparently, I've missed some details, but I definitely can't catch the problem. Here are my configuration files (or most relevant parts).

root-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="... .dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="... .service" />

<import resource="data.xml" />
<import resource="security.xml" />
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="sitelocale" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

data.xml

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    " -->

<bean id="dataSource"  class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"  
    destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />   
</bean>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tsystems.javaschool.kts.domain" />
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>     
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>






<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: http://oi49.tinypic.com/ezk940.jpg Like this.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I see there is a resources folder under webapp.  Is that were all these message files end up going?

Comment: No, these are different resources :) There go css and image files only. Message files are in %projectfolder%/src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix the `basename` value with "classpath:", try to change it as follows:

```
<property name="basename" value="messages" />
```

Comment: Nope, that did not solve the problem unfortunately, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: Perhaps you need to declare the following bean: `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following should allow you to change the lang with a URL parameter named "lang" (i.e. lang=en).  This will allow you to override browser default settings and explicitly declare the language in use.

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also, ensure in the deployed webapp that the message files are located under WEB-INF/classes/ if you are going to use classpath:messages as a basename.

Comment: So, should I remove <mvc:interceptors> block and add these two beans to configuration?

Comment: Well, that didn't change anything either unfortunately. What else could possibly be the problem? Neither locales change nor even spring:messages appear.

Comment: Correction: now locales change how they should, though messages are still empty.

Comment: And yes, these are located at WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: This would be a weird thing to try but could you add a base messages.properties file with default values?

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you add this at the top

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```